# set difference for duplicates in the second range, alternative remove_copy

Tags: c++, stl

I have two arrays or vectors, say:

```
  int first[] = {0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,3};
  int second[] = {1,3};
```

I would like to get rid of the 1s and 3s in the first set, **set_difference** can only get rid of the first occurrences of these values however this is not what I want to have.

Should I do this with **remove_copy** by iterating on the second range and each time remove one entry from the first set.

What would be the best way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a specialised set_difference:

```
template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator set_difference_any( InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                                   InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
                                   OutputIterator result )
{
  while ( first1 != last1 && first2 != last2 )
    if ( *first1 < *first2 ) {
      *result = *first1;
      ++first1;
      ++result;
    } else if ( *first2 < *first1 ) {
      ++first2;
    } else {
      ++first1;
      //++first2; // this is the difference to set_difference
    }
  return std::copy( first1, last1, result );
}
```

Then apply it to the problem:

```
#include "set_difference_any.h"
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> result;
set_difference_any( boost::begin( first ), boost::end( first ),
                    boost::begin( second ), boost::end( second ),
                    std::back_inserter( result ) );
```

This algorithm is linear (max. `last1-first1 + last2-first2` comparisions)

Comment: @Umut: indeed, it didn't. I was thinking `set_intersection`. Fixed, now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should write simple function or functional which returns `true` if element is in `second` and `false` otherwise (lets call it `ok`). And then use `std::remove_if` or `std::remove_copy_if`:

```
first.erase(std::remove_if(first.begin(), first.end(), ok));
```

P.S. considered that `first` is `std::vector<int>` and not array.

Comment: std::remove_if should be used together with vector::erase to remove those elements physically. That's what Umut wants.

Comment: Yes Of course. But in my opinion he has difficulties with this part. That's why I put only this part. Will edit to be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure set_difference won't work? The standard in 25.3.5 says

> This section defines all the basic set
>   operations on sorted structures. They
>   also work with multisets containing
>   multiple copies of equivalent
>   elements.

And the description of set_difference just says it gives you everything in first not in second, which is what you want.

Comment: I tried with vectors indeed the description seems to be what I am looking for but if I am not mistaken it is not taking all the occurrences...

Comment: set_difference works, but only removes as many elements from `first` as there are equivalent elements in `second`.

Comment: From C++ standard template library a tutorial and introduction:Duplicates are possible if elements occur more than once in the first source range. The number of occurrences of equal elements in the destination range is the difference between the number of their occurrences in the first source range minus the number of occurrences in the second source range

Comment: @Umut: if your tutorial gets the difference between equality and equivalence wrong, you should consider using another tutorial :) To nitpick: `a==b` -> `a` and `b` are _equal_; `!(a<b) && !(b<a)` -> `a` and `b` are _equivalent_.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution, for when `second` has more than a few elements: make an `std::set` (or `unordered_set`) of the elements in `second`, then loop through `first`, removing anything that is not the set. (By loop I mean `for`, `while`, `remove_if`, whatever.)